# How to implement the card swipe and display its transaction from firestore in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, card

I am looking for a way to implement the transaction page for the respective accounts.
I have card widget it has the account information and below it have a list of transaction for the respective account. When i swipe the card it has show the next account and its respective transaction.

my data from the firestore looks like, here ac01, ac02 and ac03 are dynamic values

```
{
    "ac01": [
      {
        "ac": "ac01",
        "m": "Theater",
        "t": "10:00 PM",
        "a": "-$24",
        "i":"theater"
      },
      {
        "ac": "ac01",
        "m": "Uber",
        "t": "5:00 PM",
        "a": "-$24",
        "i": "car"
      },
      {
        "ac": "ac01",
        "m": "Target",
        "t": "3:21 AM",
        "a": "-$219",
        "i": "shopping"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "ac02": [
      {
        "ac": "ac02",
        "m": "Payment",
        "t": "5:00 PM",
        "a": "-$24",
        "i": "coins"
      },
      {
        "ac": "ac02",
        "m": "Starbucks",
        "t": "2:13 PM",
        "a": "-$42",
        "i": "contentCut"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "ac03": [
      {
        "ac": "ac03",
        "m": "Hilton Hotel",
        "t": "10:13 PM",
        "a": "-$173",
        "i": "hotel"
      },
      {
        "ac": "ac03",
        "m": "Ikea",
        "t": "1:30 PM",
        "a": "-$328",
        "i": "home"
      }
    ]
  },
```

expected output

[image: expected output]

Below is my code

```
List cards = [];
Map data = {};

transactionData() async{

final dataDB = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Transaction').doc(getUid()).get();
    snapshot = dataDB;
    final Map documentData = snapshot.data() as Map;

    cards = documentData as List;

    setState(() {
      data = cards[0];
    });
  }
```

i am passing the data in the below method.

```
CardSelector(
     cards: cards.map((e) => CardPage(e)).toList(),
     onChanged: (i) {
        setState(() {
          data = cards[i];
        });
     }),

AmountPage(data, controller),
```

can someone please help me to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you show your code implementation? Without progress or code, we can't tell exactly how are your approaching this task and how to help/fix

Comment: Hi, i have updated my code. The problem i am facing is that i couldn't able to set the data correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the Data structure of my Firestore data and its working now.